# Why the input of `keras.experimental.SequenceFeature` must be a `SpareTensor`?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to migrate my seq2seq model to TensorFlow 2.0. However, I have an issue in the feature column input layer.

In TensorFlow 2.0, they provide an input layer for sequence data, `keras.experimental.SequenceFeatures`, but I HAVE TO PUT a SpareTensor.

Actually, all sequence data is not a SparseTensor. Why did they design to put the SpareTensor?

Answer (score 0):

They use `SpareTensor` to represent sequence data which have an arbitrary sequence length. However, input sequence data must have the same maximum sequence length.